# Реальный размер Базы Данных, как считать?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, centos, mariadb

У меня есть генератор на php который генерирует записи в БД на MariaDB, на 5 колонок.

```
CREATE TABLE `bazis_numbers` (
  `id` int(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bazis1` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `number` int(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bazis2` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bazis3` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `numbers_id_uindex` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Пример данных

```
'7816627', '712', '2551777', '947', '821'
```

Мне нужно сгенерировать около 500 миллионов записей, я рассчитывал размер БД исходя из того что 1 цифра в utf это 1 байт, у нас в БД в общей сложности 27 чисел будет, т.е. 27 байт

```
500000000*27 байт=13500000000 байт 
    /1024=
    13183593,75 килобайт
    /1024=
    12874 мегабайт
    /1024=
    12,57ГБ
```

У меня сервер на 15ГБ, сгенерировав 7816627 записей, решил проверить диск,
оказалось что стало на 2,7ГБ меньше, т.е выходит что 371,67 байт на строку выпало, и такими темпами для ДБ надо уже 235Гб!!!

Проверил через MySQL Workbench, показывает совсем другие данные 
https://yadi.sk/i/7WXqAOSXoXJqX
проанализировал с помощью ncdu, нашел те самые 2,7 ГБ, которые тут 2,8
https://yadi.sk/i/l70-8i_LoXLBX

Comment: У вас поля типа int, они всегда 4 байта вне зависимости от хранимого числа. размер в скобках для int значения не имеет, он только декларативно ограничивает вас от вставки больших значений.

Comment: И вся innoDB лежит в ibdata

Comment: А mysql-bin - это редо логи на случай краха. После бекапа базы их можно стирать, кроме последнего, рабочего

Comment: С другой стороны вопрос в накладных расходах на хранение. там же не просто данные лежат, там у них заголовки есть, информация для индексов и т.п. Плюс какое то место в каждой странице должно резервироваться для удлинения записей. Плюс к этому, если вы изначально вставите все поля NULL, а потом update установите значения, то запись может не уместится где лежала и она мигрирует в другой блок, оставив второй свой заголовок в старом блоке. в общем тонкостей слишком много

Comment: [Mike](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike), Спасибо за ответы, попробую удалить и посмотреть как будет работать. Исправлять таблицу не планирую, она будет как источник.